# Is there a command line tool in cygwin to copy a file to the clipboard?

Tags: windows, command-line, cygwin, clipboard

I'd like to do something like this:

- On the command line, copy a file to the Windows clipboard
- In Windows Explorer, paste the file/files into a current location

Is there a simple tool to do this, in cygwin or elsewhere?

Comment: How does this fit into your wider workflow? I ask because AFAIK this isn't possible either using any Cygwin tool or the Windows command shell, and I'm wondering if there's a different way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Came to ask the same question. The way it fits into my workflow is: I work mostly on command line, mostly Emacs. To send a file as outlook mail attachment, I have to open explorer and copy from explorer and paste in outlook. If I can copy the "file" into clipboard on command line, I don't have to open explorer.

Answer (score 6):

Try the `clip` utility that comes with Windows.

```
CLIP

Description:
    Redirects output of command line tools to the Windows clipboard.
    This text output can then be pasted into other programs.

Parameter List:
    /?                  Displays this help message.

Examples:
    DIR | CLIP          Places a copy of the current directory
                        listing into the Windows clipboard.

    CLIP < README.TXT   Places a copy of the text from readme.txt
                        on to the Windows clipboard.
```

Comment: This won't allow the file to be pasted via windows-explorer. If you run `clip < filename` then Windows explorer disables `paste` as the clipboard only contains the file contents, not whatever an explorer `copy` would capture.

Comment: @AdrianPronk Yes, sorry, good point.  I misread the question.  Searching, it doesn't appear that there is a good alternative for file copying that would then work with explorer.

Comment: In Cygwin, the canonical method to do what you're suggesting is to redirect to `/dev/clipboard`, rather than invoke a Windows utility program. You can also read from `/dev/clipboard`, which means you can use it in all sorts of exciting *nix-y pipelines and workflows. That doesn't answer the OP's question either, though!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this tool `https://github.com/roryyorke/picellif`. This is a Windows commandline tool. Put it into your `PATH` in Cygwin. I actually use it along with `winpty` like this in `.bashrc`

`alias cf='winpty picellif'`

Answer (score 0):

With Cygwin:

```
user@computer ~$ echo "foo bar" |clip

user@computer ~$ cat /dev/clipboard
foo bar
```